# What does -1 mean in pytorch view?

Tags: python, pytorch, reshape, dimensions

As the question says, what does `-1` do in pytorch `view`?

```py
>>> a = torch.arange(1, 17)
>>> a
tensor([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
         11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.])

>>> a.view(1,-1)
tensor([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
          11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.]])

>>> a.view(-1,1)
tensor([[  1.],
        [  2.],
        [  3.],
        [  4.],
        [  5.],
        [  6.],
        [  7.],
        [  8.],
        [  9.],
        [ 10.],
        [ 11.],
        [ 12.],
        [ 13.],
        [ 14.],
        [ 15.],
        [ 16.]])
```

Does it (`-1`) generate additional dimension?
Does it behave the same as numpy `reshape` `-1`?

Comment: As far as I know (I'm no pro..), that the dimension given -1 will be adapted to the other ones. So `a.view(-1,1)` will result in a vector with the dimension `17x1` because there are 17 values - so `v.view(1,-1)` will result in a `1x17` vector.. .

Comment: if you are wondering what `x.view(-1)` does it flattens the vector. Why? Because it has to construct a new view with only 1 dimension and infer the dimension -- so it flattens it. In addition it seems this operation avoids the very nasty bugs `.resize()` brings since the order of the elements seems to be respected. Fyi, pytorch now has this op for flattening: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html or see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66500823/1601580

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, it does behave like `-1` in `numpy.reshape()`, i.e. the actual value for this dimension will be inferred so that the number of elements in the view matches the original number of elements.

For instance:

```py
import torch

x = torch.arange(6)

print(x.view(3, -1))      # inferred size will be 2 as 6 / 3 = 2
# tensor([[ 0.,  1.],
#         [ 2.,  3.],
#         [ 4.,  5.]])

print(x.view(-1, 6))      # inferred size will be 1 as 6 / 6 = 1
# tensor([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]])

print(x.view(1, -1, 2))   # inferred size will be 3 as 6 / (1 * 2) = 3
# tensor([[[ 0.,  1.],
#          [ 2.,  3.],
#          [ 4.,  5.]]])

# print(x.view(-1, 5))    # throw error as there's no int N so that 5 * N = 6
# RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: size '[-1 x 5]' is invalid for input with 6 elements

print(x.view(-1, -1, 3))  # throw error as only one dimension can be inferred
# RuntimeError: invalid argument 1: only one dimension can be inferred
```

Comment: what if we have -1 by it's own? e.g. I have in front of me this: `correct[:k].view(-1)`. What does that do in that special case?

Comment: @CharlieParker: this would flatten the tensor (similar to [`torch.flatten(correct)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html)), i.e., returning a tensor with a single dimension containing all the elements. E.g., running `x.view(-1)` after the commands in my answer would return `tensor([0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])`, i.e., a tensor with a single dimension, of size 6.

Answer (score 7):

I love the answer that Benjamin gives https://stackoverflow.com/a/50793899/1601580

> Yes, it does behave like -1 in numpy.reshape(), i.e. the actual value for this dimension will be inferred so that the number of elements in the view matches the original number of elements.

but I think the weird case edge case that might not be intuitive for you (or at least it wasn't for me) is when calling it with a single -1 i.e. `tensor.view(-1)`.
**My guess is that it works exactly the same way as always except that since you are giving a single number to view it assumes you want a single dimension.** If you had `tensor.view(-1, Dnew)` it would produce a tensor of two dimensions/indices but would make sure the first dimension to be of the correct size according to the original dimension of the tensor. Say you had `(D1, D2)` you had `Dnew=D1*D2` then the new dimension would be 1.

For real examples with code you can run:

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(1, 5)
x = x.view(-1)
print(x.size())

x = torch.randn(2, 4)
x = x.view(-1, 8)
print(x.size())

x = torch.randn(2, 4)
x = x.view(-1)
print(x.size())

x = torch.randn(2, 4, 3)
x = x.view(-1)
print(x.size())
```

output:

```
torch.Size([5])
torch.Size([1, 8])
torch.Size([8])
torch.Size([24])
```

---

## History/Context

I feel a good example ([common case early on in pytorch before](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/flatten-layer-of-pytorch-build-by-sequential-container/5983) the flatten layer was [official added](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html) was this common code):

```
class Flatten(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, input):
        # input.size(0) usually denotes the batch size so we want to keep that
        return input.view(input.size(0), -1)
```

for sequential. In this view `x.view(-1)` is a weird flatten layer but missing the squeeze (i.e. adding a dimension of 1). Adding this squeeze or removing it is usually important for the code to actually run.

---

## Example2

if you are wondering what `x.view(-1)` does it flattens the vector. Why? Because it has to construct a new view with only 1 dimension and infer the dimension -- so it flattens it. In addition it seems this operation avoids the very nasty bugs `.resize()` brings since the order of the elements seems to be respected. Fyi, pytorch now has this op for flattening: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html

```
#%%
"""
Summary: view(-1, ...) keeps the remaining dimensions as give and infers the -1 location such that it respects the
original view of the tensor. If it's only .view(-1) then it only has 1 dimension given all the previous ones so it ends
up flattening the tensor.

ref: my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66500823/1601580
"""
import torch

x = torch.arange(6)
print(x)

x = x.reshape(3, 2)
print(x)

print(x.view(-1))
```

output

```
tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
tensor([[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5]])
tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

see the original tensor is returned!

Comment: note `.view()` seems to avoid the nasty bugs `resize` usually brings.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this works similar to [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, **the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions**.

If you have `a = torch.arange(1, 18)` you can view it various ways like  `a.view(-1,6)`,`a.view(-1,9)`, `a.view(3,-1)` etc.

Comment: what if we have -1 by it's own? e.g. I have in front of me this: `correct[:k].view(-1)`. What does that do in that special case?

Answer (score 1):

[From the PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view):

> ```
> >>> x = torch.randn(4, 4)
> >>> x.size()
> torch.Size([4, 4])
> >>> y = x.view(16)
> >>> y.size()
> torch.Size([16])
> >>> z = x.view(-1, 8)  # the size -1 is inferred from other dimensions
> >>> z.size()
> torch.Size([2, 8])
> ```

Comment: what if we have -1 by it's own? e.g. I have in front of me this: `correct[:k].view(-1)`. What does that do in that special case?

Answer (score 0):

-1 infers to 2, for instance, if you have

```
>>> a = torch.rand(4,4)
>>> a.size()
torch.size([4,4])
>>> y = x.view(16)
>>> y.size()
torch.size([16])
>>> z = x.view(-1,8) # -1 is generally inferred as 2  i.e (2,8)
>>> z.size()
torch.size([2,8])
```

Comment: what if we have -1 by it's own? e.g. I have in front of me this: `correct[:k].view(-1)`. What does that do in that special case?

Answer (score 0):

`-1` is a PyTorch alias for "infer this dimension given the others have all been specified" (i.e. the quotient of the original product by the new product). It is a convention taken from [`numpy.reshape()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Hence `t.view(1,17)` in the example would be equivalent to `t.view(1,-1)` or `t.view(-1,17)`.