# the meaning of (-1,)+x.shape[2:] where x is a torch.tensor

Tags: pytorch, torch

I once saw code segment using `torch.reshape` as following:

```
for name, value in samples.items():
    value_flat = torch.reshape(value, (-1,) + value.shape[2:]))
```

what does `(-1,) + value.shape[2:])` means here? Here value is of type `torch.tensor`.

Answer (score 0):

- `(-1,)` is a one element *tuple* containing `-1`.
- `value.shape[2:]` selects from the third to last elements from `value.shape` (the shape of tensor `value`).

All in all, what happens is the tuple gets concatenated with the [`torch.Size`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.size.html) object to make a new tuple. Let's take an example tensor:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(2, 3, 63, 64)

>>> x.shape[2:]
torch.Size([64, 64])

>>> (-1,) + x.shape[2:]
(-1, 64, 64)
```

When using `-1` in [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html), it indicates to ['put the rest of the dimensions on that axis'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792316/what-does-1-mean-in-pytorch-view). Here it will essentially flatten the first and second axes (batch and channel) together.

In our example, the shape will go from `(2, 3, 64, 64)` to `(6, 64, 64)`, *i.e.* if the tensor has four dimensions, the operation is equivalent to

```
value.reshape(value.size(0)*value.size(1), value.size(2), value.size(3))
```

but is certainly very clumsy to write it this way.