# Taking the last state from BiLSTM (BiGRU) in PyTorch

Tags: python, lstm, pytorch

After reading several articles, I am still quite confused about correctness of my implementation of getting last hidden states from BiLSTM.

1. [Understanding Bidirectional RNN in PyTorch (TowardsDataScience)](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-bidirectional-rnn-in-pytorch-5bd25a5dd66)
2. [PackedSequence for seq2seq model (PyTorch forums)](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/packedsequence-for-seq2seq-model/3907/2)
3. [What's the difference between “hidden” and “output” in PyTorch LSTM? (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302810/whats-the-difference-between-hidden-and-output-in-pytorch-lstm)
4. [Select tensor in a batch of sequences (Pytorch formums)](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/select-tensor-in-a-batch-of-sequences/8613)

The approach from the last source (4) seems to be the cleanest for me, but I am still uncertain if I understood the thread correctly. Am I using the right final hidden states from LSTM and reversed LSTM? This is my implementation

```
# pos contains indices of words in embedding matrix
# seqlengths contains info about sequence lengths
# so for instance, if batch_size is 2 and pos=[4,6,9,3,1] and 
# seqlengths contains [3,2], we have batch with samples
# of variable length [4,6,9] and [3,1]

all_in_embs = self.in_embeddings(pos)
in_emb_seqs = pack_sequence(torch.split(all_in_embs, seqlengths, dim=0))
output,lasthidden = self.rnn(in_emb_seqs)
if not self.data_processor.use_gru:
    lasthidden = lasthidden[0]
# u_emb_batch has shape batch_size x embedding_dimension
# sum last state from forward and backward  direction
u_emb_batch = lasthidden[-1,:,:] + lasthidden[-2,:,:]
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a general case if you want to create your own BiLSTM network, you need to create two regular LSTMs, and feed one with the regular input sequence, and the other with inverted input sequence. After you finish feeding both sequences, you just take the last states from both nets and somehow tie them together (sum or concatenate).

As I understand, you are using built-in BiLSTM as in [this example](https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/02-intermediate/bidirectional_recurrent_neural_network/main.py) (setting `bidirectional=True` in **nn.LSTM** constructor). Then you get the concatenated output after feeding the batch, as PyTorch handles all the hassle for you.

If it is the case, and you want to sum the hidden states, then you have to

```
u_emb_batch = (lasthidden[0, :, :] + lasthidden[1, :, :])
```

assuming you have only one layer. If you have more layers, your variant seem better.

This is because the result is structured (see [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=lstm#lstm)):

> **h_n** of shape (*num_layers* * *num_directions, batch, hidden_size*): tensor containing the hidden state for t = seq_len

By the way,

```
u_emb_batch_2 = output[-1, :, :HIDDEN_DIM] + output[-1, :, HIDDEN_DIM:]
```

should provide the same result.

Comment: Your assumptions are right, I am using an built-in BiLSTM (BiGRUs, respectively) to avoid the hassle and I am experimenting with multi-layer architectures. Thank you for your response. @toBTW: Yes but if I would use an 'output' I would first need to unpack it from Packed Sequence into Padded Sequence, which is something I wanted to avoid as well. I still have a bunch of questions:

@1: Why is not my variant OK for 1 layer?

@2: Is there any place in the docs (or other official sources) I missed, that says something about ordering the hidden states in case of BiRNN in lasthidden variable?

Comment: 1. it is fine, but I was surprised to see unusual numbers
2. for all layers first (index 0) is normal RNN, then reversed. See the source of nn.RNNBase

Answer (score 3):

Here's a detailed explanation for those working with unpacked sequences:

`output` is of shape `(seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size)` (see [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=gru#torch.nn.GRU)). This means that the output of the forward and backward passes of your GRU are concatenated along the 3rd dimension.

Assuming `batch=2` and `hidden_size=256` in your example, you can easily separate the outputs of both forward and backward passes by doing:

```py
output = output.view(-1, 2, 2, 256)   # (seq_len, batch_size, num_directions, hidden_size)
output_forward = output[:, :, 0, :]   # (seq_len, batch_size, hidden_size)
output_backward = output[:, :, 1, :]  # (seq_len, batch_size, hidden_size)
```

(Note: the `-1` tells pytorch to infer that dimension from the others. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479902/how-view-method-works-for-tensor-in-torch) question.)

Equivalently, you can use the [`torch.chunk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.chunk) function on the original `output` of shape `(seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size)`:

```
# Split in 2 tensors along dimension 2 (num_directions)
output_forward, output_backward = torch.chunk(output, 2, 2)
```

Now you can [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather) the last hidden state of the forward pass using `seqlengths` (after reshaping it), and the last hidden state of the backward pass by selecting the element at position `0`

```
# First we unsqueeze seqlengths two times so it has the same number of
# of dimensions as output_forward
# (batch_size) -> (1, batch_size, 1)
lengths = seqlengths.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(2)

# Then we expand it accordingly
# (1, batch_size, 1) -> (1, batch_size, hidden_size) 
lengths = lengths.expand((1, -1, output_forward.size(2)))

last_forward = torch.gather(output_forward, 0, lengths - 1).squeeze(0)
last_backward = output_backward[0, :, :]
```

Note that I subtracted `1` from `lengths` because of the 0-based indexing

A this point both `last_forward` and `last_backward` are of shape `(batch_size, hidden_dim)`

Comment: I guess you made a mistake up there. Should this not be : ```output = output.view(-1, 2, 2, 256)   # (seq_len, batch_size,  num_directions,hidden_size)``` instead? and then it would simply be : ```output_forward = output[:, :, 0, :]   # (seq_len, batch_size, direction)
output_backward = output[:, :, 1,  :]  # (seq_len, batch_size, direction)```

Comment: I wrote this answer when pytorch was in v0.4.0 and if you look at the documentation back then (https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.0/nn.html#gru), the output dimensions were `seq_len, batch, hidden_size * num_directions`, however in the current version they are `seq_len, batch,  num_directions * hidden_size`. I updated the answer considering the new ordering. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tested the biLSTM output and h_n:

```py
# shape of x is size(batch_size, time_steps, input_size)
# shape of output (batch_size, time_steps, hidden_size * num_directions)
# shape of h_n is size(num_directions, batch_size, hidden_size)
output, (h_n, _c_n) = biLSTM(x) 

print('first step (element) of output from reverse == h_n from reverse?', 
    output[:, 0, hidden_size:] == h_n[1])
print('last step (element) of output from reverse == h_n from reverse?', 
    output[:, -1, hidden_size:] == h_n[1])
```

**output**

```
first step (element) of output from reverse == h_n from reverse? True
last step (element) of output from reverse == h_n from reverse? False
```

This confirmed that the h_n of the reverse direction is the hidden state of the first time step.

So, if you really need the hidden state of the last time step from both forward and reverse direction, you should use:

```
sum_lasthidden = output[:, -1, :hidden_size] + output[:, -1, hidden_size:]
```

**not**

```
h_n[0,:,:] + h_n[1,:,:]
```

As `h_n[1,:,:]` is the hidden state of the first time step from the reverse direction.

So the answer from @igrinis

```
u_emb_batch = (lasthidden[0, :, :] + lasthidden[1, :, :])
```

is not correct.

But in theory, last time step hidden state from the reverse direction only contains information from the last time step of the sequence.