# Why return self.head(x.view(x.size(0), -1)) in the nn.Module for pyTorch reinforcement learning example

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I understand that the balancing the pole example requires 2 outputs. [Reinforcement Learning (DQN) Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html)

Here is the output for self.head

```
  print ('x',self.head)  
  x = Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2, bias=True)
```

When I run the epochs below is the outputs:

```
print (self.head(x.view(x.size(0), -1)))
return self.head(x.view(x.size(0), -1))

tensor([[-0.6945, -0.1930]])
tensor([[-0.0195, -0.1452]])
tensor([[-0.0906, -0.1816]])
tensor([[ 0.0631, -0.9051]])
tensor([[-0.0982, -0.5109]])
...
```

The size of x is:

```
x = torch.Size([121, 32, 2, 8])
```

So I am trying to understand what x.view(x.size(0), -1) is doing?

I understand from the comment in the code that it's returning:
Returns tensor([[left0exp,right0exp]...]).

But how does x which is torch.Size([121, 32, 2, 8]) being reduced to a tensor of size 2?

Is there an alternative way of writing that makes more sense?  What if I had 4 outputs.  How would I represent that?  Why x.size(0).  Why -1?
So appears to take self.head with 4 outputs to 2 outputs.  Is that correct?

At the bottom is that class I am referring:

```
class DQN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, h, w, outputs):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)

        # Number of Linear input connections depends on output of conv2d layers
        # and therefore the input image size, so compute it.
        def conv2d_size_out(size, kernel_size = 5, stride = 2):
            return (size - (kernel_size - 1) - 1) // stride  + 1
        convw = conv2d_size_out(conv2d_size_out(conv2d_size_out(w)))
        convh = conv2d_size_out(conv2d_size_out(conv2d_size_out(h)))
        linear_input_size = convw * convh * 32
        self.head = nn.Linear(linear_input_size, outputs)

    # Called with either one element to determine next action, or a batch
    # during optimization. Returns tensor([[left0exp,right0exp]...]).
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.bn3(self.conv3(x)))
        return self.head(x.view(x.size(0), -1))
```

Answer (score 2):

`x.view(x.size(0), -1)` is flattening the tensor, this is because the Linear layer only accepts a vector (1d array). To break it down, `x.view()` reshapes the tensor of the specified shape (more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479902/how-does-the-view-method-work-in-pytorch)). `x.shape(0)` returns 1st dimension of the tensor (which is the batch size, this should remain the constant). The `-1` in `x.view()` is a filler, in other words, its dimensions that we don't know, so PyTorch automatically calculates it. For example, if `x = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4])`, to reshape the tensor to a `2x2`, you could do `x.view(2,2)` or `x.view(2,-1)` or `x.view(-1,2)`.
The output shape is not a tensor shape of `2`, but that of `121,2` (the `121` is the batch size, and the `2` comes from the Linear layers `output`). So to change the output size from 2, to 4, you would have to change the outputs argument in the `__init__` function to 4.