# How to restructure the output tensor of a cnn layer for use by a linear layer in a simple pytorch model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Given a `pytorch` input dataset  with dimensions:

```
dat.shape = torch.Size([128, 3, 64, 64])
```

[image]

This is a supervised learning problem: we have a separate `labels.txt` file containing one of `C` classes for each input observation.  The value of `C` is calculated by the number of distinct values in the labeles file and is presently in the single digits.

I could use assistance on how to mesh the layers of a simple mix of convolutional and linear layers network that is performing multiclass classification.  The intent is to pass through:

- two cnn layers with maxpooling after each
- a linear "readout" layer
- softmax activation before the output/labels

Here is the core of my (faulty/broken) network.  I am unable to determine the proper size/shape required of:

```
 Output of Convolutional layer -> Input of Linear [Readout] layer
```

```
class CNNClassifier(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3,padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(32*16*16, C)
        self.softmax1 = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.maxpool(F.leaky_relu(x))
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxpool(F.leaky_relu(x))
        x = self.linear1(x)  # Size mismatch error HERE 
        x = self.softmax1(x)
        return x
```

Training of the model is started by :

```
        Xout = model(dat)
```

This results in :

> RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [128 x 1568], m2: [8192 x 6]

at the `linear1` input.  What is needed here ? Note I have seen uses of wildcard input sizes e.g via a `view`:

```
    ..
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = self.linear1(x)  # Size mismatch error HERE
```

If that is included then the error changes to

> RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [28672 x 7], m2: [8192 x 6]

Some pointers on how to think about and calculate the cnn layer / linear layer input/output sizes would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The error

You have miscalculated the output size from convolutional stack. It is actually `[batch, 32, 7, 7]` instead of `[batch, 32, 16, 16]`.

You have to use `reshape` (or `view`) as output from `Conv2d` has 4 dimensions (`[batch, channels, width, height]`), while input to `nn.Linear` is required to have 2 dimensions (`[batch, features]`).

Use this for `nn.Linear`:

```
self.linear1 = nn.Linear(32 * 7 * 7, C)
```

And this in `forward`:

```
x = self.linear1(x.view(x.shape[0], -1))
```

### Other possibilities

Current new architectures use pooling across channels (usually called global pooling). In PyTorch there is an [`torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html) (or `Max` pooling). Using this approach allows you to have variable size of height and width of your input image as only one value per channel is used as input to `nn.Linear`. This is how it looks:

```
class CNNClassifier(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, C=10):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3)
        self.pooling = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(32, C)
        self.softmax1 = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.maxpool(F.leaky_relu(x))
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxpool(F.leaky_relu(x))
        x = self.linear1(self.pooling(x).view(x.shape[0], -1))
        x = self.softmax1(x)
        return x
```

So now images of `torch.Size([128, 3, 64, 64])` and `torch.Size([128, 3, 128, 128])` can be passed to the network.

Comment: The addition of the `AdaptiveAvgPool2d` is perfect for the case where you might have multiple image sizes; I thought of adding it myself. +1

Comment: Thx!  For the first approach and size `32x7x7`  Did you calculate that via `O = (W - K + 2*P)/S + 1` ?

Comment: @javadba You can find exact formulas in PyTorch docs. This time I've just `printed` `shape` attribute before `linear`. Also, usually, with `kernel_size=3` in `Conv` you use `padding=1` so the shape stays the same (and whole thing is easier to follow).

Answer (score 2):

So the issue is with the way you defined the `nn.Linear`. You set the input size to `32*16*16` which is not the shape of the output image but the number `32`/`16` represent the number of "channels" dim that the `Conv2d` expect for the input and what it will output.

If you will add `print(x.shape)` before the entrance to the fully connected layer you will get:

```
torch.Size([Batch, 32, 7, 7])
```

So your calculation should have been `7*7*32`:

```
self.linear1 = nn.Linear(32*7*7, C)
```

And then using:

```
x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
x = self.linear1(x)
```

Will work perfectly fine. You can read about the what the `view` does in: [How does the "view" method work in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479902/how-does-the-view-method-work-in-pytorch)