# How does tensor permutation work in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I'm struggling with understanding the way `torch.permute()` works. In general, how exactly is an n-D tensor permuted? An example with explaination for a 4-D or higher dimension tensor is highly appreciated.

I've search across the web but did not find any clearly explaination. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tensors are contiguous 1D data lists in memory. What differs is the interface PyTorch provides us with to access them, this all revolves around the notion of **stride**, which is the way this data is navigated through. Indeed on a higher level, we prefer to reason our data in higher dimensions by using tensor **shapes**. The following example and description are still valid for higher dimensions tensors.

The permutation operator offers you a way to change the way you access the tensor data by *seemingly* changing the order of dimensions. Permutations return a view and do not require a copy of the original tensor (as long as you do not make the data contiguous), in other words, the permuted tensor shares the **same** underlying data.

At the user interface, permutation reorders the dimensions, which means the way this tensor is indexed changes depending on the order of dimensions supplied to the [`torch.Tensor.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html) method.

Take a simple 3D tensor example: `x` shaped `(I=3,J=2,K=2)`. Given `i<I`, `j<J`, and `k<K`, `x` could naturally be accessed via `x[i,j,k]`. Concerning the underlying data being accessed, since the stride of `x` is `(JK=4, J=2, 1)`, then `x[i,j,k]` corresponds to `_x[i*JK+j*J+1]` where `_x` is the underlying data of `x`. By "corresponds to", it means the data array associated with tensor `x` is being accessed with the index `i*JK+j*J+1`.

If you now were to permute your dimensions, say `y = x.permute(2,0,1)`, then the underlying data would remain the same (in fact [`data_ptr`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.data_ptr.html) would yield the same pointer) but the interface to `y` is different! We have `y` with a shape of `(K,I,J)` and accessing `y[i,j,k]` translate to `x[k,i,j]` ie. `dim=2` move to the front and `dim=0,1` moved to the back... After permutation the stride is no longer the same, `y` has a stride of `(IJ, I, 1)` so `y[i,j,k]` corresponds to `_x[i*IJ+j*I+1]`.

If you want to read more about views and strides read, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479902/what-does-view-do-in-pytorch).